# timeout on wait

Tags: java

If I do

```
synchronization (someobject) {  
    while (someobject.need2wait()) {  
      someobject.wait(timeout);  
    }  
}
```

What happens when the timeout expires? If another thread has locked `someobject` will it be interrupted?

Comment: Did you read the fairly comprehensive documentation on `Object.wait()` before asking the question? If so, could you show exactly which bit of the documentation seems unclear or incomplete?

Comment: When the thread waits, it releases the synchronization lock. When the timeout expires, the thread wakes up and will reacquire the synchronization lock WHEN AVAILABLE (i.e. either now if no thread has it locked, or as soon as the lock is free). The thread will then resume executing immediately after the wait statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation. You can try it for yourself with the following code - you will notice that no thread gets interrupted:

```
public class TestWait {
    private static volatile boolean ready = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Object lock = new Object();
        Runnable waitingTask = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(lock) {
                    while(!ready) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Going to wait here");
                            lock.wait(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Thread interrupted");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("I'm done waiting");
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(waitingTask).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main interrupted");
        }
        ready = true;
        System.out.println("ready");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the Javadocs for Object

> The thread T is then removed from the wait set for this object and
>   re-enabled for thread scheduling. It then competes in the usual manner
>   with other threads for the right to synchronize on the object; once it
>   has gained control of the object, all its synchronization claims on
>   the object are restored to the status quo ante - that is, to the
>   situation as of the time that the wait method was invoked. Thread T
>   then returns from the invocation of the wait method. Thus, on return
>   from the wait method, the synchronization state of the object and of
>   thread T is exactly as it was when the wait method was invoked.